# Как реализовать корзину в телеграм боте на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Скажу сразу , в программировании - новичок , пишу где-то 2 месяца.

Где-то месяц назад начал писать бота в телеграм на языке Python, пишу на библиотеке телебот.
Практически все сделал, осталось доделать корзину, но не понимаю как осуществить затеянное, снизу приложу примерную схему работы корзины(заранее извиняюсь за свой корявый почерк[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: получилось реализовать корзину ?

Answer (score 0):

Я вам советую прикрутить базу данных, точнее вам без нее не обойтись. Так как вы новичок в программировании, и если не хотите сильно заморачиваться - советую копнуть в сторону sqlite3. Просто отличный способ для реализации корзины в телеграм-боте. А чтоб было проще работать с этой базой, скачайте бесплатный софт - SQLiteStudio. И плюс ко всему гайдов/видео в интернете на эту тему очень много.
У каждого пользователя в телеграмме есть уникальный `id`, и по этому идентификатору сможете записывать товары в базу данных, которые добавил пользователь в корзину. А там уже зависит только от вас:)

Comment: лучше redis , по сути данные в корзине надо хранить только до оформления заказов) хотя для новичков может сложно будет